# ODBC MySQL Connector: Does not work with chars like "ä, ö, ü"

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysql-connector

I've got a MSSQL database which is connected with a "linked server" in mssql to an odbc connection to mysql. MySQL Connector Version is 5.2.3w and the charset is set to UTF-8.

I try to execute the following statement, just for example in mssql:

```
Insert Into openquery(VERBINDUNGSSERVERNAME, 'SELECT `D` FROM  `atd_ec_helper_delete`' )
Select * FROM ( 

Select 'Ä' as a
UNION
Select 'Ö' as a
UNION
Select 'ü' as a
UNION
Select '?' as a
UNION
Select '~' as a

) b
```

It adds five rows, but only the two last rows (? and ~) are inserted. The first three rows have no data in the row "D", it's just empty. It's not null.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to take the "w" ODBC-driver, not the "a" version. The "w"-version is for unicode characters and the "a" for ANSI. In my case I have to take the "w" version.

The strings won't cut anymore, but with Openquery the special chars will be set wrong in my case. Solution is to use

```
EXEC('Insert Into ....') AT LINKEDSERVERNAME
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work vice versa ...

```
Insert Into LocalMSSQLTableName Select * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVERNAME, 'Select * FROM MySQLTable')
```

The only solution in my case is to encode special chars to avoid these problems.